# How do you get an ID of a clicked div element in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

My question is how to get an ID of an element that has just been clicked? (JavaScript)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the target element (in all browsers except IE) and srcElement (in IE) in order to retrieve the clicked element:

```
function click(e) {
  // In Internet Explorer you should use the global variable `event`  
  e = e || event; 

  // In Internet Explorer you need `srcElement`
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement;

  var id = target.id;
}
```

However be aware of event bubbling. The `target` may not be the element you expect.

Comment: `target` is the element where the event originates. in standards browsers, `currentTarget` is the element attached to whatever function is running. ie doesn't have an equivalent to `currentTarget` that I'm aware of.

Comment: this will sound like a stupid question but i cant figure out what to feed my function with? is "e" supposed to be an event and when i am calling a function i should do sth like: click(onclick)? and after it i could use the variable id?

Comment: You have to make your function be an event handler for something, probably a container element surrounding the elements you're interested in.

Comment: @necker if you're doing it inline: `<div id="foo" onclick="click(event);" />`

if you do it with `addEventListener`/`attachEvent`, `e` is the default parameter and will be the relevant event instance. prototype  probably has a wrapper method using these calls to add your handlers.

Answer (score 2):

The "target" attribute of the event object passed to your event handler (or, in the case of IE, set up as a global variable) will be a reference to the element affected. If you're setting up your event handlers with Prototype, then:

```
 function clickHandler(ev) {
   var id = ev.target.id;
   // ...
 }
```